# How are baselines for extinction rates established?

Tags: speciation, extinction

At the time of 2010, the UN Environment Programme estimated that *150-200* species of plant, insect, bird and mammal become extinct every 24 hours, and, that this is nearly *1000 times greater* than "natural" rates. ([source](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2010/aug/16/nature-economic-security), para. 5)

My question is: How are baselines for extinction rates (regarding plant & animal species amongst the entire Earth) established, to then be able to say if an extinction rate for a given species is "normal" or not? What factors are considered most relevent?

Comment: Good question +1. Note that a species does not have an extinction rate, only a larger clade does (referring to `[..] extinction rate for a given species [..]`). The accessory question is interesting also and I think deserves its own post. Blending the two questions in the same post make it a bit broad and may discourage some to answer when they can't answer both questions.

Comment: @Remi.b I created a new post for the secondary question.. thanks for the advice :)